# appending to the beginning of a URL string using isapi 3

Tags: isapi, isapi-rewrite

Trying to take an existing URL say: domain.com/qe/info/happy/
and prepend with the following: /qe-happy/

before: domain.com/qe/info/happy/
after: new.com/info/qe-happy/

I am using asapi 3

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/qe/info/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://new.com/info/qe-%1 [NC,R=301,L]
```